# two networks in one docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, docker-network

I have a rather complex docker-compose setup. My `docker-compose` file consists of following services:

- A_mysql
- A_apache
- B_mysql
- B_apache
- B_sync

I need my **host machine** to access two different php projects via http running on `A_apache` and `B_apache`. Furthermore i need to separate the networks (one for all A_* services and one for all B_* services). The `B_sync` service needs to access the `A_mysql` database to sync data to the `B_mysql` of his own network.

How can I separate these services in two networks and access a particular service (`A_mysql`) from another network (`B_sync`)? How do I set a fixed IP for this service?

I know that putting all services in one and the same network would deprecate the sync job, but since this is a smoke test , this wouldn't fit the production environment.

Comment: Are you using kubernetes? Can you provide additional information on how these projects are hosted.

Comment: I don't use kubernetes. The production environment is split up in two physically different machines without the use of docker. It's just a plain php project on a apache server and a mysql db and another php project with the same configuration on another server. My goal is to simulate this environment for development and testing purposes using plain docker-compose (if possible).